# How do I link models across different Datasources?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

At first glance I am assuming the answer is no simply because when I look at the queries Cake creates, there is no way for one datasource to know how to build queries for the associated tables. At least to me. What I have is a UserModel that hasOne TwitterProfileModel via User.twitter_profile_id. My UserModel uses MySQL and my TwitterProfileModel uses MongoDB. The only solution I can think of is fetching the TwitterProfile data via my UserModel's afterFind callback. I am curious to know if there is a solution more native to CakePHP and if the way I am planning of approaching this issue is the best way. I've looked at the documentation and I see no mentioning of a situation like mine.

**EDIT:**
I am aware that datasources do not talk to each other. My question is what steps can I follow in order to be able to retrive an associated model that is from a different datasource

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to CakePHP at all but to databases: You can not associate different db systems tables by joins. Use the same db system for both tables if you really have to use sql joins if not you'll need to fetch the records in the afterFind() as you already do it.

Comment: This is indeed related to CakePHP. In the framework exists Models that  are associated to database via datasources. I am not asking if i can "associate different db systems tables by joins" I am asking what steps I can take to be able to associate models that use different datasources. Next time you need clarity on a question, please pose a comment rather than downvoting.